# Private field and overriding the getter and setter methods

Tags: java

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Block {
    private boolean collided = false;

    public boolean hasCollided() {
        return collided;
    }

    public void markCollided() {
        collided = true;
    }
}
```

I have 4 sub classes for the Block class. Those class also require to receive the collided variable. That means the two methods should be overridden by the 4 sub classes of Block. How can I make it work?

If I try to override it, it will show error because sub classes does not contain such a variable in it.

How can I receive the collided variable in all sub classes?

Also,I created an array of block class that array contains 4 subclass objects.Is it possible to set different values for the collided variable for each object,while traversing the array?
In short,the colllided variable can be unique for each object in the array?

Comment: make it `protected` not `private`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Why? The methods are public and inherited

Comment: @Manasa Please show an example of your subclass. Unclear why you need to override them

Comment: @cricket_007 *error because sub classes does not contain such a variable in it* - looks like he is trying to touch the variable itself

Comment: please check the edited question@ScaryWombat

Comment: *How can I receive the collided variable in all sub classes?* call the `hasCollided()` method

Comment: yes.It is not showing error after making it protected.Thank you! Please check last paragraph of my question.What is your idea?@ScaryWombat

Comment: What have you tried?  My idea is to try coding and learning from the experience

Comment: @Manasa ScaryWombat's intention is - you should not be trying to access the property from child classes, but instead be using the methods to check the state - the child classes shouldn't care about the property

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes.I got.it.I am going to give a try.Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Collided variable cannot be unique for 4 elements. It can only have 2 values. True or False. By "unique", you mean "independent"? Yes, that is how instance variables work.

Comment: @cricket_007 By unique,I mean independent values,that is either true or false.I have about 20 objects of 4 subclasses of abstract class in an array.Each object should have its own state.Is that possible?@cricket_007 –

Comment: Again, each object having their own state is how instance variables work in object oriented programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the public methods `hasCollided(), markCollided()` etc., because `collided` is a private variables for class `Block` .

The fact the 4 sub classes  extends `Block`  ,that doesn't mean can access private fields. Block provided public `hasCollided,markCollided` to access its private variables.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the collided variable directly because it is private. But 
you can use the hasCollided() method of the superclass to return the parent class' collided variable.

```
public class subBlock {


public boolean hasCollided() {
    return super.hasCollided();
}

public void markCollided() {
    super.hasCollided()= true;
}
}
```